# Reflections doesn't find object subtypes

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to get all the classes in a package by using Reflections.
When I use code of a concrete class (A in this example) it works and prints the subclases information (B extends A so it prints B information), but when I use it with Object class it doesnt work. How can I fix it?

This code works:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(REFLECTION_PACKAGE);
Set<Class<? extends A>> allClasses = reflections.getSubTypesOf(A.class);

System.out.println("numberOfLCasses: " + allClasses.size());
System.out.println("classes: " + allClasses.toString());
```

This code doesn't:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(REFLECTION_PACKAGE);
Set<Class<? extends Object>> allClasses = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);

System.out.println("numberOfLCasses: " + allClasses.size());
System.out.println("classes: " + allClasses.toString());
```

Comment: What is import for `Reflections`?

Comment: What’s the output

Comment: yes, you have to use the library:

Comment: <dependency>
     <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
     <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
     <version>0.9.11</version>
 </dependency>

Comment: it sais there is 0 classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [documented behavior](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.reflections/reflections/latest/org/reflections/scanners/SubTypesScanner.html).

> public SubTypesScanner()
>
> created new SubTypesScanner. will exclude direct Object subtypes
>
> public SubTypesScanner(boolean excludeObjectClass)
>
> created new SubTypesScanner.
>
> Parameters:
>       excludeObjectClass - if false, include direct Object subtypes in results.

The below should return subtypes of `Object.class`

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(REFLECTION_PACKAGE,new SubTypesScanner(false));
Set<Class<? extends Object>> allClasses = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);

System.out.println("numberOfLCasses: " + allClasses.size());
System.out.println("classes: " + allClasses.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the new 0.10.x API

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections( "com.my.package", SubTypes.filterResultsBy( s -> true));
Set<Class<?>> subTypes = reflections.get( SubTypes.of( Object.class).asClass());
subTypes.forEach( t -> {
   log.info( "Class: {}", t.getName());
});
```

Comment: With this lib, I'm on a strange behavior. 

1. When executing inside my IDE (intelliJ), it works well, as I expect.
2. If I execute via maven command-line, it works 
3. But when I execute the application in standalone mode (from packaged .jar file execution), subtypes list is empty. 

Details: my app is a Spring boot app with .jar packaging. 

- If I try to scan a external library package, it works in third cases. 
- If I scan an internal package (in my own code), no sub class is found. As if my code would not be in loaded classpath.