# Reflections - Empty sub class list on my own package

Tags: java, reflection

With [Reflections lib](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections/), I'm on a strange behavior.

This following code results on server environment with an **empty list**.

```java
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.package");

Set<Class<?>> subTypes = reflections.get( SubTypes.of( Object.class).asClass());
```

I've also tried this one

```java
    reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .setScanners(new SubTypesScanner(false), new ResourcesScanner())
                .addUrls(ClasspathHelper.forJavaClassPath())
                .filterInputsBy(new FilterBuilder()
                        .includePackage("my.package"))));
```

Depending on execution context:

1. When executing inside my IDE (intelliJ), it works well, as I expect.
2. If I execute via maven command-line, it works also
3. But when I execute the application in **standalone mode** (from packaged .jar file execution), subtypes list is empty.

Details:

My app is a **Spring boot** app with .jar packaging.

- If I try to scan an **external library package**, it works in third cases.
- If I scan an **internal package** (in my own code), no sub class is found. As if my code would not be in loaded classpath.

> I've read Reflection lib is based on .class files.
> Anyway, in my jar, I can also find this class files....

Any idea ?

Comment: Linked to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59378578/reflections-doesnt-find-object-subtypes